# Undefined Variable "resources"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

For some reason, Visual Studio Code is telling me that a list I made, doesn't exist. And that's strange, because it *does* exist! Here is my code, or, part of it, at least.

```
class Adventurer:
def __init__(self, name, coins, resources, health):
    # Define class properties here
    name = name
    coins = coins
    resources = resources
    health = 5

    # Begin by querying the user
    userSez = input("Welcome to Astroway!\nType, 'look around' to see your surroundings.\nType 'examine <object>' to examine an object.")
    self.readInput(userSez, 0)

# What did the user say?
def readInput(self, userInput, playLevel):
    if playLevel == 0:
        print("You look around, and find you are in a desert. Around you, there are prickly cacti, a small chest, and a seemingly endless desert wasteland.")    
        userSez = input("Here are your choices of examination:\n\t• cacti\n\t• chest\n")
        self.readInput(userSez, 1)
    if playLevel == 1:
        if userInput == "cacti":
            userSez = input("You reach out to touch one of the cacti. Ouch! You lose 1 heart of health and have 4 left. What next?\n")
            health = health - 1
            self.readInput(userSez, 1)
        elif userInput == "chest":
            userSez = input("You open the chest. Inside, you see a golden key. What could this do? You pick it up. You put it in your inventory. What next?\n")
            resources[0] = "golden_key"
            self.dialogue(0)
```

So yeah, I hope you can see why I'm confused here. And by the way, this is the error that appears when i hover. `Undefined variable 'resources'pylint(undefined-variable)` And when I run it, it says i used it BEFORE it was defined...

Comment: You defined `resources` as a local variable to `__init__`. You probably meant `self.resources = ...`. And the same for all other variables

Comment: i saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943652/python-too-many-self-in-class and it said that you could just use local variables but im not really sure how that works, i guess my judgement was mistaken

Comment: But that's exactly the opposite where you ***need*** to use local variables and not the instance's ones...

Comment: oh. well, that explains it

Comment: Maybe you should go over [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). Specifically the [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) chapter

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not assigning your attributes correctly, you should specify self. before assigning them

```py
def __init__(self, name, coins, resources, health):
    # Define class properties here
    self.name = name
    self.coins = coins
    self.resources = resources
    self.health = 5 # Btw, why set to 5 if you are getting health in the params?
```

Later when you are referring to those variables, like in `resources[0] = "golden_key"`
you should use `self.resources[0] = "golden_key"`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `resources` is not defined for the code inside the `readInput` method.  As you are defining a variable with that name in your class's constructor, I assume that you mean for that variable to be an instance variable.  To do that, you need to treat `resources` as an attribute of the instance of the class by using `self`:

```
class Adventurer:
    def __init__(self, name, coins, resources, health):
        ...
        self.resources = resources
        ...
    
    def readInput(self, userInput, playLevel):
        ...
                self.resources[0] = "golden_key"
```